# Python connected components in skimage label vs ndimage vs cv2

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image, ndimage

I have a need to find connected components in a binary uint8 image of size 480x640. I have over 3500 such images that need their connected components (8 way connectivity) found. I found that using `skimage.measure.label` has been the fastest even though `ndimage` is supposed to be faster on binary images. CV2's `connectedComponents` has been the slowest so far.

Are there any faster ways to achieve the same in the same libraries or using alternate libraries?

skimage

```
measure.label(
    (image == LABEL_DICT[feature_1]).astype(np.uint8),
    connectivity=2,
    background=0,
    return_num=True,
)
```

ndimage

```
structure = np.array([
                    [1, 1, 1],
                    [1, 1, 1],
                    [1, 1, 1]
                    ])
label_img, num_components = scipy.label(
    (image == LABEL_DICT[feature_1]).astype(np.uint8),
    structure
)
```

cv2

```
cv2.connectedComponents((image == LABEL_DICT[feature_1]).astype(np.uint8), connectivity=8)
```

Comment: "ndimage is supposed to be faster" How so? I'm sure the folks at skimage put in effort to make their functions efficient also.

Comment: You can try `dip.Label(image == LABEL_DICT[feature_1], connectivity=2)` from [DIPlib](https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/regions.html#dip-Label-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-L-dip-uint--dip-uint--dip-uint--dip-StringArray--dip-String-CL). Note that the input must be a binary image (or logical array), not uint8 like you're doing with the other libraries. The output can be cast back to a NumPy array using `np.asarray(...)`.

Comment: Flipping back and forth between image formats is likely going to slow the effective time per image.

Comment: @fmw42 Do you mean the `.astype(np.uint8)`, or are you referring to my comment about casting the output of the DIPlib function to NumPy? If it's the latter, there's no data copy, it's just creating a new object of a different type, pointing to the same pixel data.

Comment: @Cris Luengo. Simply a question about additional time for casting between Numpy and other image formats such as DIPlib, PIL, etc or any other process such as binarization or converting datatype.  That would need to be included, if significant(?), when comparing to any one any one connected component time performed in Skimage and keeping the image in compatible image format.  Or is that time insignificant compared to the connected component processing?

Comment: @fmw42 I agree it would be fair to include the necessary conversion steps in any time comparisons. There is a chance their time is significant, given that a well-implemented connected component analysis is pretty cheap.

Comment: I just compared times. On my machine (M1 Mac), OpenCV is 10x as fast as the next best option. It seems that it uses parallelism. NDimage and DIPlib are about equally fast. Skimage is more than 2 times slower.

Comment: The current implementation of `connectedComponents` was introduced in OpenCV 4.5.2 (April 2021, PR: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/19631), it is significantly faster than their previous implementation, which was slower than DIPlib's in my testing. If OpenCV is slowest for you, you might just be using an older version of OpenCV. I suggest you upgrade.

Comment: I read online that ndimage outperfroms skimage on binary images

Comment: I'm using opencv 3.4. Will update to opencv  >4.5.2 and benchmark again